# Have backbone.js reroute me to the login page and fire the action

Tags: backbone.js

When someone visits my page I want them to be rerouted to the login page and fire the action.

I can not get this code to work, hope someone can help me out.

```
window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'login': 'login'
    },
    index: function(){
        Backbone.history.navigate('login');
    },
    login: function(){
        alert('route');
        userLoginView = new UserLoginView();
    }
});

$(function() {
    var appRouter = new AppRouter;
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

I bet it has something to do with slashes maybe, something small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the navigate function of the router, not Backbone.history ( http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate ). You also have to specify the parameter trigger, so the corresponding action is triggered.

Here's the solution:

```
index: function() {
    this.navigate('login', {trigger: true});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it. I tried using the trigger, but it didn't work. I think using 'this' in combination with it did the trick. Thanks!